# How to output a JavaScript code in Zapier Code properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, output, zapier

I have a Zap that is triggered everytime a new Facebook LeadAd is generated.
In the second step I created a JS code to match some fields of the leadad (Adset Name + Term) with a property of an object  inside an array of objects with filter function.

Example:

```
let campaign = inputData.adset_name + inputData.term;

let logic = [
        {
            Campaign: "Adsetname+term",
            Doctors: "Name 1 - Name 2",
            ID: "xxxxxxxx - yyyyyyyy",
            Count: "2",
            Zone: "Neighborhood",
            UF: "City"
        }
//There's a lot of these objects inside the array with other data.
]

let filtro = logic.filter(x => {
    return x.Campaign === campaign;
});


output = [
  {
    ID: filtro.ID,
    UF: filtro.UF,
    Count: filtro.Count
  }
];
```

The main goal here is to match the incoming adset name + term with the adset name + term of a determined object inside the array, so it will return the other info linked to this specific object.

But the code isn't outputing any info into this object created. It runs with no errors, bur returns no data of the object.

[Result of the step test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiOEl.png)

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `filtro` is set to a filtered array of objects:

```js
filtro = [
  {ID: 'asdf', UF: 'qwer'}
]
```

In your output, you're accessing `filtro.ID`, which is `undefined`. An `Array` doesn't have an `ID` property.

Instead, you probably want `ID`, `UF` and `Count` for *each* item in `filtro`. In that case, you can use the `Array.map` function:

```js
output = filtro.map(item => {
  return {
    ID: item.ID,
    UF: item.UF,
    Count: item.Count
  }
})
```

This will return an array of objects. If this code is an action (instead of a trigger) subsequent zap steps will run for each item you return. See [these docs](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/use-javascript-code-in-zaps#output-data-from-code-steps) for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot @xavdid!!! I get to solve the problem just by returning the function filtro instead of creating an output. 

```
let filtro = logic.filter(x => {
    return x.Campaign === campaign;
});

return filtro;
```

And this already got me the object I needed and its properties.. :)